# ag-grid table: Vertical-align: middle

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

I am using the framework ag-grid ()
I have changed the row-height to 50px.

```
<div 
  className="ag-theme-balham"
  style={{ 
    height: '90vh', 
    width: '100%',
    'font-size': '18px',
    'row-height': '50px'
    }} 
    >
    <AgGridReact        
        rowHeight={50}
        columnDefs={columnsTaenze}
        rowSelection={'multiple'}
        onFirstDataRendered={this.autoSizeAll}
        rowDragManaged={true}
        enableColResize={true}
        animateRows={true}
        rowData={this.props.tabledata}
        enableFilter={true}
        onRowDragEnd={this.onRowDragEnd}>
    </AgGridReact>
</div>
```

Sadly, I can not manage to center the cell vertically.

I have tried to change many classes, including `ag-cell`.
My css I tried:

```
.ag-cell{
    line-height: 50px;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

But the cell isn`t centered:
[image]

**//Edit / TIP**

If you want to do yourself a favor, you should switch to [react-table](https://github.com/tanstack/table) from Tanstack NOT AG-GRID company

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use below CSS. No need to use hard-coded values in CSS for height.

```
.ag-row .ag-cell {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; /* align horizontal */
  align-items: center;
}
```

Have a look at this plunk: [ag-grid: text-align vertically center](https://plnkr.co/edit/rh3K50WraWbiLCqRrtgz?p=preview)

Comment: I'm trying to do horizontal alignment and also use type: "rightAligned", but this `flex` solution seems to break the horizontal alignment. I'm trying to pass padding to cell via CSS but only `paddingRight` and `paddingLeft` work, do you have any clue on what I should do?

Comment: If we do this, the cellStyle won't be effective

Comment: You break CSS styles of a grid.

Comment: This will break text-ellipsis so you won't have the "..."
Display flex doesn't work with ellipsis

Answer (score 9):

You can set cell style to following

```
 cellStyle: {
        'height': '100%',
        'display': 'flex ',
        'justify-content': 'center',
        'align-items': 'center ',
      },
```

This will work fine.

Comment: I like this way rather than modifying all ag-cell, more flexible

Comment: Not working for me sadly

Answer (score 7):

To build on @Paritosh's answer...

You don't have to overwrite the ag-grid styles themselves. You can do something like this in your own stylesheet:

```
.cell-vertical-align-text-left {
  display: flex!important;
  align-items: center;
}

.cell-vertical-align-text-right {
  display: flex!important;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  text-align: right!important;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Then in your ag-grid column definition use your custom css style in the `cellClass` property.

```
var columnDefs = [
  {
    headerName: "Alerts",
    colId: 'invoice_issues',
    editable: false,
    cellClass: "cell-border cell-vertical-align-text-right",
    valueGetter: showInvoiceIssues,
    autoHeight: true,
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

After upgrading ag-grid to version 28, I've noticed the vertical center alignment has been lost.

Below is a solution that retains the text-overflow: ellipsis (...) and overflow: hidden CSS rules when the text exceeds cell width.

Tested in ag-grid version 28.2.0

```
.ag-cell-wrapper {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Didn't work for me, sorry.  Ellipsis is still gone.

Comment: This unfortunately destroys the `colDef: { autoHeight: true, }`...

Answer (score 0):

If you are noticing the same problem as the user above after upgrading to v28, probably you'll need to adjust the CSS/SASS imports. Not sure why this is not more explicit on the changelog.

In summary, you will need to drop the /dist part in the path:

```
<!-- old path -->
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://unpkg.com/ag-grid-community@28.0.0/dist/styles/ag-grid.css" />

<!-- new path -->
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://unpkg.com/ag-grid-community@28.0.0/styles/ag-grid.css" />
```

Reference:

https://www.ag-grid.com/archive/28.0.0/angular-data-grid/global-style-upgrading-to-v28/

https://www.ag-grid.com/archive/28.0.0/angular-data-grid/global-style-upgrading-to-v28-css/

Answer (score 0):

Consider adding the AG Grid option:

**enableCellTextSelection={true}**

I'm not sure why, this this then changes the text from being near the top:

[image]

to centered vertically:

[image]